# Model view controller: where do I put the function QObject::connect(Object1, Signal1, Object2, Slot2); ? In view or controller?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a doubt about Model View Controller. I put the function connect in class Controller but I don't know if it's right or wrong. Maybe in the view is better. How can I do? The user should make request with the controller and not the view.

```
class Model{
public:
string name;
}

class View:public QMainWindow{
public:
Model* m;
View(QWidget* parent, Model* m):QMainWindow(parent), m(m){
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    QPushButton* button=new QPushButton("Button", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100, 100),QSize(200, 50)));
}

class Controller{
private:
    Model* m; View* v;
public:
    Controller(Model* m, View* v):m(m),v(v){
        QObject::connect(v.button, SIGNAL (clicked()), v.label, SLOT(Click());
    }
    void Click(){
        v.label->setText(m.name);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
Model m;
Qwidget* parent=new QWidget();
View v(parent, &m);
Controller(&m,&v);
v.show();
}
```

Comment: Is the user gonna be able to change the data shown in the view? if not, there's no need for the controller.

Comment: If you put it in the View then the View will need to know about the Model then you break the design pattern MVC. I don't see any problem with your design.

Comment: In Qt there are already some design patterns implemented. When you use the framework I strongly recommend to learn how the classes are intended to be used. Creating a view, which inherits from _QMainWindow_ and making it child of a _QWidget_ doesn't make much sense to me. You can learn about model/view programming [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).